# Is it necessary to move auth scaffold after upgrading to laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-7

I've recently upgraded my laravel project to laravel 7 from laravel 5.8. As we all know in laravel 7 auth scaffold is moved in laravel/ui. is it really necessary to move my auth scaffold under laravel/ui directory after upgrading to laravel 7 ..?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is not entirely necessary, it is highly advisable in the long run.

`Laravel/UI` will be supported and maintained by the Laravel team and will recieve updates.

Who knows what features they may add in future and you will want to take advantage of them!